# How to update the browser cache in the $http success function in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular and I implemented a table using angular that can provides different views to the user based on the view selected from a drop down. Whenever user changes the selected view, an $http call will fetch the data for that specific view (using the view id) and updates the table (set the view to the new one with a different id in the scope object). everything works fine. The only issue is when the user leaves the page and then hits the back button to see the table again, the table doesn't show the last viewed one in table and the reason is browser fetches the data for the cached view id (old id) which is the one when the page was loaded not the one that asynchronously was fetched during the $http call. So I think I need to somehow update the browser cache in the $http success function (whenever the new view is returned) so the browser knows the last viewed one. I would appreciate for any guide on this issue. 
the http call is like this:

```
$scope.fetchView = function(){
        //this is the view Id that is selected by user
        // this view will be deleted in the backend and a new one will be created (with a new Id)
        var viewId = $scope.view.id;
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: contextPath + '/views/' + viewId

        }).success(function (data) {
            //set the view object to the new one with a new Id but the browser cache still holds the old id
            $scope.view = data.view;

        }).error(function () {
            $log.info('An error occurred during ...');
        });
    };
```

Comment: Please add some code.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ppovoski  I have added the $http function to my question.